# Problema intermitente no layout de sugestão de perguntas similares: sobreposição de questões similares

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, perguntas, design

Ao inserir o título de alguma publicação, o sistema já começa a sugerir questões similares. Isso acontece tanto no site principal quanto aqui no meta, e é intermitente.

No site principal:

[image: sobreposição no site principal]

No meta:

[image: sobreposição no meta]

Dependendo de alguma interação (não descobri qual interação é essa, parece que tempo pode ser um dos fatores) após alguma edição no título as sugestões deixam de ficar sobrepostas e apenas uma listagem aparece. Editar o título pode acarretar na criação dessa sobreposição.

Detectado no Firefox 74.0 (64-bits), Windows 10. Não tenho nenhum plugin instalado para alterar a exibição do SOpt.

---

Uma maneira que encontrei de reproduzir o bug, ao menos na minha máquina:

- abrir nova pergunta no meta
- digitar "Problema de layout"
- esperar carregar a lista de sugestões de similares
- se não carregar, apertar espaço
- esperar carregar a lista de sugestões de similares
- continuar digitando até que o título seja "Problema de layout no site"
- scroll na lista de sugestões

[image: mais um exemplo do problema no layout]

Usando o Firefox 81.0.2 64 bits, em um Windows 10 64 bits.

Vale lembrar o comentário do [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8275/problema-intermitente-no-layout-de-sugest%c3%a3o-de-perguntas-similares-sobreposi%c3%a7%c3%a3o?noredirect=1#comment32612_8275):

> Consegui reproduzir, [...], no entanto passado 3 segundos a "busca antiga" é removida

Comment: Tenho configurações semelhantes, no entanto o mesmo problema não ocorre, então creio que possa ser um problema no seu driver de video com o Firefox, e sim, eu já tive problemas com FF e placas (ou drivers) semelhantes, incluindo no Developer Tools, "bugs" que eu inclusive reportei a alguns anos, mas como é complicado pra turma do FF testar sem ter a mesma placa então acabou que levou uns 4 anos pra corrigirem e nem se sabe se foi corrigido, recebi uma mensagem deles perguntando se o problema tinha sido resolvido, mas até então eu não tinha mais o computador pra confirmar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, como eu citei é intermitente. Então talvez ocorreu algo no meu uso que não ocorreu no seu, ou algo que ocorreu no seu que "corrigiu" a exibição. Parece que quando se clica em algo tudo se normaliza, mas não fui a fundo pesquisar sobre esse problema

Comment: Quando ocorrer selecione o inspetor de elemento e veja se os elementos por trás existem, se existirem é BUG da SE, caso contrário, é um problema semelhante a alguns que tive justamente com o FF e variantes placas de video.

Comment: Botei em breakpoint de modificação no nó `document.getElementById('js-similar-questions-expandable').children[0]`. Quando há um carregamento Ajax com as novas questões similares, o navegador para neste breakpoint, porém não quando ocorre a "limpeza" da "sombra" que fica por baixo. Acontecia algo assim contigo, @GuilhermeNascimento?

Comment: Consegui reproduzir, é BUG da SE mesmo, no entanto passado 3 segundos a "busca antiga" é removida, por isso nem sempre é evidente.

Comment: Ainda é reproduzível, o bug? Se sim, podem dar mais detalhes de como chegar lá? Um dev tentou reproduzir ontem e não conseguiu :)

Comment: @JNat, continua ocorrendo. Vou ver se consigo fazer de modo reproduzível, mas a priori: digito algo no título, espero carregar a lista de similares, digito mais algo, dou scroll.

Comment: Só por desencargo de consciência veja se o seu navegador não possui alguma opção experimental de vídeo ou scroll ativada. Talvez uma opção possa estar interferindo na exibição.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não tenho nenhuma configuração fora do padrão, mas darei uma olhada nisso

Comment: Continuo sem conseguir reproduzir, @JeffersonQuesado... podes experimentar numa janela incognito, com todas as extensões desactivadas? E ver se aparecem erros na consola?

Comment: @JNat não tenho extensões ativadas. Tentarei fazer no modo incógnito, assim que possível volto a reportar

Comment: @JNat, como no momento estou longe do computador, tentei reproduzir no Firefox Mobile para iOS, sem sucesso. Também não reproduzi no Safari mobile

Comment: O Firefox atualizou para a versão 82.0 e não consegui mais reproduzir, @JNat

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, continua acontecendo contigo?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado continua sim, a dois dias no SOen notei isso. PS: uso Firefox também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, veja se o seu FF já foi atualizado para versão >=82.0 ?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Jeff no FF 82 ainda apresenta o BUG https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VQcL.png ... Mas parece ter outro, as vezes o "content:" esta vindo vazio, mas poderia ser algum erro lá no servidor ... confirmando, FF 82 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeW7f.png

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já verificou o cache?

Comment: @AugustoVasques como eu disse em outros comentários, o bug não é fácil de reproduzir, tem um "timing" certo. Olha só, acabei de abrir essa janela anônima: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHe6m.png -- não tem cache então, e mesmo assim o bug ocorre, como eu disse é questão de "acertar o tempo", por isso talvez vocês não estejam notando. Eu não analise o código js responsavel por isso, mas um chute que acho que tem chances de ser assertivo, é que estão usando clearTimeout de forma errada, o que deve estar anulando o evento que limpa os resultados antigas, então 3 segs depois ele finalmente limpa

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu dei uma inspecionada na fonte e cheguei a essa [informação](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/links/) sobre o tipo de link `.s-link__grayscale` no [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/), mas não achei mais nada sobre documentação de bug indo por esse caminho.